# Java Micro Edition (JME) SDK for Mac OS X or Linux

Tags: linux, macos, java-me

The question is clear from the title.

Is there an SDK for the Java Micro Edition available for Mac OS X or Linux? Or does one need Windows XP to develop JME applications?

Comment: Although question accepted, my Linux answer might help ;) Good luck

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, with a 'but'

There is no WTK (Wireless Toolkit) from the main vendors available for Mac ([NetBeans Wiki reference](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqJ2MEOtherOpSys)) so basically you can't debug nor test the code. But, you can use an emulator from a third co: [MPowerPlayer](http://mpowerplayer.com/)

If you are using netbeans in any other OS but windows, you still can download and add the J2ME packages using the tools/plugins menu. 
Then you can add the MPowerPlayer to the IDE as a J2ME platform. Netbeans (and i guess any other IDE with J2ME WTK support) will recognize it as a valid WTK,

I've posted an specific entry about this in my blog, but it's in spanish, although maybe you can follow the images. Give it a try, and don't hesitate to ask anything:
[J2ME in Mac Os with NetBeans](http://crazypointer.blogspot.com/2008/08/j2medesarrollo-de-aplicaciones-j2me-en.html)

Answer (score 2):

Offically Sun's WTK is available only on Linux and Windows, however both SDKs can be used on Mac to compile J2ME applications.
Unfortunately the emulator and the preverifier will not work (since they are not Java based) so you will not be able to test your application.

To solve this problem you can use MicroEmulator or MPowerPlayer for both emulation and preverification (you can also use PhoneME for preverification).

This is a good guide to setup you development environment using [Eclipse](http://javablog.co.uk/2007/08/29/j2me-development-on-os-x/) and this one is good for [Netbeans](http://javablog.co.uk/2008/01/17/j2me-development-on-os-x-revisited/).

But, if I can give an advice (I'm working since two years on J2ME development and I'm a Mac user), it is better if you develop on Windows or Linux through a virtual machine, because the two emulators do not have a very good compliance to the JSR's standard and do not include all of them.
Moreover on OSX it will be very difficult for you to test features like Bluetooth or LocationAPIs.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans has a JME SDK

Comment: Thats true but look here http://www.netbeans.org/downloads/index.html Java ME is only included for windows xp...

Answer (score 1):

May be this is helpful, I've found a Java ME Developer Studio for Mac OS X, developed by Motorola, I haven't tested yet, it's only and EA Release, I'll try this one, and I'll let u know in a subsequent post,

http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/javame/downloads/

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough ... I just set this up **5 minutes ago** on Linux.

You will need:

http://linux.com/archive/feature/122050

http://java.sun.com/products/sjwtoolkit/download.html <-- WTK

The WTK installer will ask where your JDK is. Do

```
find . -name "jar" -type f
```

and then where you have

```
/usr/lib/jvm/foo/bar/bin/jar
```

Knock of the 'jar' and give that path to the installer. This will install **ktoolbar** which includes a phone emulator.

The download netbeans and install the mobile addons

**This is not pure J2ME, but includes most of the API**

I am using it to develop an application for my SE-C902

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the official SDK for OSX can be downloaded here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/downloads/sdk30-mac-jsp-137878.html. Microemulator, http://www.microemu.org, also works well, and I've heard people use MPowerPlayer with success.

Comment: I'm sure it is by now, four and a half years later.

Comment: haha :D can you please update something that works, I really need that.

Comment: The official SDK link works, as of December 2019; however, that's for the ME SDK 3.0. Oracle is on 8+ now. AFAIK, that's the last ME version made for Mac; everything now apparently is Windows or Linux: [Java ME SDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javameoverview.html#SDK) and [Oracle Java ME SDK Downloads](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/sdk-downloads.html) - links accessed 6 December 2019.